# String extraction and http request creation

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a specific string (URL address) from each JSON result (in the tweets.txt file)  and then create HTTP GET request with the extracted URL address, the HTTP response should be saved as a new HTML file in the directory.
The string I'm trying to extract is the value of specific JSON value.

for example:
"display_url": **test.com/y8HTdfdfKMFz**

my code:

```
# # # # TWITTER STREAM LISTENER # # # #
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
"""
This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
"""
def __init__(self, fetched_tweets_filename):
    self.fetched_tweets_filename = fetched_tweets_filename

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print(data)
        with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
            tf.write(data)
        return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
    return True


def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':

# Authenticate using config.py and connect to Twitter Streaming API.
hash_tag_list = ["donal trump"]
fetched_tweets_filename = "tweets.txt"

twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename, hash_tag_list)
```

The JSON result:

```
{"created_at":"Wed Nov 14 11:12:59 +0000 2018","id":1062664687601496064,"id_str":"1062664687601496064","text":"This is test https:\/\/t.co\/V3tNm99tdn  fdfd\n\n#osectraining","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":961508561217052675,"id_str":"961508561217052675","name":"line Sec","screen_name":"oseining","location":"US","url":"https:\/\/www.ocurity.com","description":"field","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2,"friends_count":51,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":3,"created_at":"Thu Feb 08 07:54:39 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/961508561217052675\/1518076913","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"osectraining","indices":[44,57]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/V3tNm99tdn","expanded_url":"https:\/\/pastebin.com\/y8HTKMFz","display_url":"pastebin.com\/y8HTKMFz","indices":[13,36]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"tr","timestamp_ms":"1542193979536"}enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you 100% but, if you save the tweets to a file, as a json dump you can easily convert the json result to a python dict as follows:

```
import json
with open('tweets.txt') as handle:
    dictdump = json.loads(handle.read())
```

and then you have just a python dict value:

```
my_url = dictdump['display_url']
```

and then use `requests` module to send a get/post whatever you want to the url

```
import requests
r = requests.get(my_url)
```

Comment: error   : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request2.py", line 3, in <module>
    dictdump = json.loads(handle.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 81 column 1 (char 5379 - 470853)

Answer (score -1):

This is building on top of @Avishay Cohen's answer, since you are opening the file in append mode, there should be more than one json string in your `tweets.txt`
So what you could do is something like this:

```
import json
import requests
with open('tweets.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        tweet_json = json.loads(line)
        response = requests.get(tweet_json.get('display_url')) if 'display_url' in tweet_json else {}
        if response and response.status_code()==200:
            print(response.text)
```

Comment: There is some problem. response.txt doesn't create. When I add "print response" for debugging I got this output: {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}

Comment: The json which you have attached doesn't contain any key called 'display_url', can you add the name of the attribute which you are referring as url?

Comment: "display_url":"test.com"

Comment: well this is not present in the outside part of the dictionary itself, its embedded within the entities list, are you sure that there will only be one item in the 'entities' list ?

Comment: Take a look in the JSON result in the question. there is a value:  "display_url":"pastebin.com\/y8HTKMFz". I need to extract the URL part, "pastebin.com\/y8HTKMFz"  in this case.